# MSI installer. Error 1603

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am using MSI installer to upgrade my service from one version to another in Windows 7 and in windows server. The upgrade in windows 7 machine is working fine but it is failing in Windows Server 2012.
Here is what I am doing -

> 1. I am stopping the old release service using C# code.

```
NativeWinServiceMethod.ControlService(service, NativeWinServiceMethod.SERVICE_CONTROL.STOP, ref lpServiceStatus);
```

> 2. Then removing all the files from installed path using MSI installer exe.
> 3. And finally installing the new version again.

**This upgrade works fine in windows 7 but failing in windows server.** 
**MSI log shows 1603**

I know the cause of it now but need a solution for it - 
**Cause** -

> MSI installer is uninstalling the previous version and starting to
>   install the new version but before the previous version could be
>   removed from the **registry**. Since service removal from registry is
>   taking time - new version service installation is failing.

Comment: Stopping service manually is a bad practice. You need to register your service within your MSI in the `ServiceControl` table and the installer will do it for you.

Comment: 1603 is almost certainly the result of the code crashing. ServiceControl in your MSI tool is the thing to use, and you haven't said what the service actually is, but occasionally a service name will change and your code won't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the response- But if there is a code crash, it should fail in all environments but the installation is just failing in server machines. Service here is a custom windows service.

Comment: I have got more information on this issue - edited my post

Comment: You should never run any code to install or upgrade services. All you need is available out of the box in the MSI and using it will make your setup very reliable. What are you using to generate the MSI? WiX? Installshield?

Answer (score 0):

While installing on Windows If you get 1603 error that maybe means you have failed to install visual studio redistributable package install problem. Maybe uninstall already installed version and try install new again can be fix this problem.